# How to setup Wi-Fi connection remotely in a mobile application through Bluetooth

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, wifi

There is a computer without any peripherals (keyboard, monitor, etc.) with Wi-Fi/Bluetooth interfaces (e.g. Raspberry Pi). I would like to find an open source solution to setup Wi-Fi connection on this computer remotely using some mobile application (as a part of this solution) through bluetooth connection.

Use case: someone wants to connect Raspberry Pi to home Wi-Fi network, he runs an application on his smartphone, connects to Raspberry Pi using Bluetooth and send Wi-Fi credentials to Raspberry Pi. Raspberry Pi receives Wi-Fi credentials and automatically connects to home Wi-Fi network.

Is there such solution ready to use? Maybe is there implemented bluetooth profile to do it? Please share any information. Thanks.

Comment: I've developed such a solution for a product, requires to design a messaging format and a simple protocol.

Mine was built using Bluetooth (classic one).

Comment: Hopefully you can find stuff here:
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bluetooth+wifi+config